# How to test a rails method through the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble testing specific zip codes in specific addresses.  I have a concern that is inherited and validated in a model. It fixes another problem of users inputing default zip codes that do not match the states that they are located in. However I ultimately need to run a migration to fix any zip codes that have been flawed up until this point.  Which brings me to my problem. Is there a way to test a specific concern, or method written in this concern through the console at all?

My concern is below.

```
module StateMatchesZipCodeConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def verify_zip_matches_state
    return unless zip.present? && state.present?

    state_search_result = query_zip_code

    unless state_search_result.nil?
      return if state_search_result.upcase == state.upcase
      return if validate_against_multi_state_zip_codes
    end
    errors[:base] << "Please verify the address you've submitted. The postal code #{zip.upcase} is not valid for the state of #{state.upcase}"
    false
  end

  private

  def query_zip_code
    tries ||= 3
    Geocoder.search(zip).map(&:state_code).keep_if { |x| Address::STATES.values.include?(x) }.first
  rescue Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError, Timeout::Error
    retry unless (tries -= 1).zero?
  end

  def validate_against_multi_state_zip_codes
    ::Address::MULTI_STATE_ZIP_CODES[zip].try(:include?, state)
  end
end
```

I've tried `User.last.address.validate_against_multi_state_zip_codes?` and wind up with a method missing.  Would anybody know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're including `StateMatchesZipCodeConcern` in your `User` model.

That means the method `validate_against_multi_state_zip_codes` will be a method on `User` instances.

You're trying to call this method on the return of the `User`'s `address` method, which is what throws `NoMethodError`. In addition, you've made this method `private` so you won't be able to call it anyway.

Put the method above the `private` line in the module and call it like this: `User.last.validate_against_multi_state_zip_codes?`

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much!